# Populating a Doc with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, autofill

I don't know why the text shows up in the Google Doc for First Name and Last Name columns but no text for the notes column. I'm not sure why, I'd also like for row 9, 10, and 11 to populate text depending on which row is selected.

```
    function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
    menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
    menu.addToUi();
    }

    function createNewGoogleDocs() {

    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1ybOPZ-Y3wIZMyZpCW3HUojb72nDF8D9ruipdphpWvBE');
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1jtR9DjOY7wvu2I9NQvZtrWBkZtDlK2c0');
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Enrollments");
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[14]) return;

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[2]} ABC Bartending and Casino 
    School`, destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[1]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{{Student ID}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Phone}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{Amount Paid}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Balance}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{Start}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{am}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{pm}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{we}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Email}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Notes}}', row[13]);

    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 15).setValue(url);

    })
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information and context about what you are trying to do? Ideally a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At least some sample documents to be able to test out what the script does and also to test any potential solutions.